# Java EE (Jakarta EE), в чем секрет популярности Tomcat?

Tags: java, java-ee

Правильно ли я понимаю что Tomcat реализует только маленькую часть всего Java EE стека, если да, то почему от такой популярный?

Спасибо.

Comment: [большого секрета тут нет](https://youtu.be/BcmUOmvl1N8?t=21)

Comment: Потому что не всегда нужен тяжёлый сервер приложений, часто достаточно лёгкого web-контейнера.

Comment: @VTT спасибо, от души посмеялся

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Был `TomEE`, он реализовывал большую часть Java EE, однако оказалось, что в современнных реалиях многие реализации не используются. Нет смысла тянуть подряд всё что угодно, когда можно подцепить только то что необходимо именно вам.

[image: Сравнение версий TomEE и Tomcat]